# RandomForest regression with pandas and sklearn: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

Getting this [similar](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32) error due to 'nan' values in data frame. Tried to replace `nan` values but it did not worked either. I don't know hat is going on.

Here is the flow,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data = {
        'sales':[10,20,30,40,50],
        'cost': [24233, 15111, 11111,np.NaN, 3422],
        'obs': [1, np.NaN, 3, 1, 2],
        'treatment': [0, 1, 0, np.NaN, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['sales','cost', 'obs', 'treatment'])

df

Out[35]: 
   sales   cost  obs treatment
0     10  24233    1         0
1     20  15111  NaN         1
2     30  11111    3         0
3     40    NaN    1       NaN
4     50   3422    2         0
```

## Preparing the training data

```
y = df['sales'] #outcome variables

X = df[[col for col in df.columns if col!='sales']] # predictors


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size =0.25, random_state=0)

#print(f'Size of train dataset: {X_train.shape[0]} rows')
#print(f'Size of test dataset: {X_test.shape[0]} rows')


#X_test
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

getting this error

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

I tried;

```
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),axis=0)
```

> TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'", 'occurred at index cost')

Comment: Your nan's are strings which is why you are getting the error when trying to use `fillna`. Replacing them with float NaNs should work (you will also need to cast the Series as float afterwards) but it would be cleaner if you solve the root problem. Why do you have string nan's in the first place? Are you reading the data from a file?

Comment: `nan` is a string to pandas. `NaN` is a float.

Comment: @ayhan Yes reading from file in real data. I just have NaN values when I read the data. I did not know nan or NaN makes any difference.

Comment: @ayhan Ok I edited `df` and changed string `nan` to `np.NaN` but the error is still persist!

Comment: @Alexander If you are still getting a TypeError saying 'int' and 'str' are not supported for '+' then that means you have strings in one of the columns. In order to use the `.mean` method you need to have numeric columns. You can try `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` but keep in mind that this will replace every string with a `NaN`.

Comment: @ayhan Thanks! When I did `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` it worked then I did `df=df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),axis=0)`.